# Power BI Create a dynamic measure from two other dynamic measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dashboard which contains a date range selector and 3 cards.
The cards contain values A and B with a third card C being the addition of the previous 2 (A+B)
I want to set it up so that when I change the dates, A, B and C will change with respect to their dates. I am able to get this working for A and B but C never updates. I was wondering if i am missing something in my DAX

```
# Here we calculate the measure A which pulls data from a table X
# The value is updated based on a date slider which is populated from the table _cal_table
A = 
VAR SelectedDateRange = SELECTEDVALUE(_cal_table[Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(X[A]),
    FILTER(
        A,
        X[date] >= MIN(_cal_table[Date]) && X[date] <= MAX(_cal_table[Date])
    )
)

# Here we calculate the measure B which pulls data from a table X
B = 
VAR SelectedDateRange = SELECTEDVALUE(_cal_table[Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM(X[B]),
    FILTER(
        A,
        X[date] >= MIN(_cal_table[Date]) && X[date] <= MAX(_cal_table[Date])
    )
)

# Here I calculate C but it does not change when the slider is changed
# I am making the large assumption that because A and B change with the slider that C
# should change automatically. I have tried to wrap it up in the same type of filters as A and B
# but that produced nothing either
C = A+B
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a sample.pbix?